# Quartz Cron Trigger with Spring - triggering new cron before last ended

Tags: java, spring, triggers, quartz-scheduler

Simple question, I think.

I have `org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean` triggering one job once a day. Because this method can last a long time (over 24 hours), will the next day at the same time a new job be executed if the last one is not ended yet?

If yes - is it possible to turn off executing new jobs until the last one is finished?

My method is trans-coding videos and some days there a lot of videos and could last long.

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636556/ensure-that-spring-quartz-job-execution-doesnt-overlap

Comment: But a different answer. But yes - now I see, that down under is not-accepted answer the same as here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the Job stateful, So it will prevent the new instance before the previous instance of the job ended.

You 'mark' a Job as stateful by having it implement the StatefulJob  interface.
You will get more about stateful job [here](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/docs/tutorial/TutorialLesson03.html)