# Spring quartz interval: what happen if method takes longer then repeat interval?

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

With all due respect `quartz` is not very clear about `repeatInterval` in this question:

what happen if the method takes longer than the `repeatInterval`, is it going to fire the trigger even if the current method didn't finish? And is it going to cause connection pooling issue if the method create data source object?

say if the method normally takes `5` seconds to finish but may surge to `10` seconds, and `repeatInterval` is set to `8000` (8 seconds)

what will happen to the next occurrence of the trigger? I did some sample test and looks like it will occur in the `16th` second because the first attempt at `8000` ms failed

is that the way it works? Is there any performance impact on the server?

Answer (score 5):

If the method execution takes longer than specified interval, the second instance of the job will be created and run concurrently.

You can annotate your `Job` instance with [@DisallowConcurrentExecution](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.1/org/quartz/DisallowConcurrentExecution.html) annotation which prevents multiple instances of the job to run concurrently.

```
@DisallowConcurrentExecution
public class TestJob implements Job {}
```

Having this, the further attempted job instances will be queued up and you have to watch out, as without any control the infinite number of job instances may queue up which may lead to issues (such as performance, race-conditions, etc).

> Is there any performance impact on the server?

As 2 jobs are performing the same operation this will have performance impact, depending on the operations you are trying to perform of course.

You can find alternatives of scheduling, also different approaches of preventing concurrent execution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636556/ensure-that-spring-quartz-job-execution-doesnt-overlap).

Comment: Thanks vtor. What is the answer if the `ConcurrentExecution` is already set to false, no current execution. if the method takes longer than the interval, when the next occurrence take place and any performance impact?

Comment: @Dreamer I've updated my answer, hope it helps >Having this, the further attempted job instances will be queued up and you have to watch out, as without any control the infinite number of job instances may queue up which may lead to issues (such as performance, race-conditions, etc).